# Moving cursor of mouse not working in iframe in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am stuck with one peculiar issue.
The use case is after searching the element go to search results.
However after the search button is clicked the mouse pointer rotates infinitely until and unless someone moves the mouse  pointer.
The issue is mouse pointer is still in rotating position even though i apply move by offset.
The entire page is nested in a frame.
Move Offset is working in previous methods but not for this
I am attaching the screenshot and code
Mouse pointer cannot be captured in screenshot

Screenshot

[image: Location of Image]
My code is as below

```
public void AddUser(){
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", Add_User);
            Select_Partner.Click();
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame("vplfWindow_organizationPicker_0");
            Wait.UntilElementDisplayed(driver, Enter_Partner_id);
            //Enter_Partner_id.SendKeys(ExcelClassTemp.ReadExcel(Excel, 2, 12, 2));
            String str = ExcelClassTemp.ReadExcel(Excel, 2, 12, 2);
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1];", Enter_Partner_id, str);
            ExcelClassTemp.release_Excel(Excel, 2);
            Search_Partner.Click();
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveByOffset(-1, -1).Perform();
}
```

Comment: Any specific requirement to use `MoveByOffset()`? How did you calculate `(-1, -1)`? Did you try `moveToElement(element)`?

Comment: -1,-1 is a random no.The thing is the mouse pointer will change to select pointer even if we change by 1 MM.
I have tried moveToElement but its not changing the position.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to switch back to Frame or 'defaultContent' after clicking the button and before moving the mouse?

Maybe your searched element that you tried to move to is in another frame... maybe you have to leave your actual Frame and enter another Frame first.

Comment: Hello AcMuD
I checked but the entire page is in single frame.

Answer (score 0):

Its working now.
Move by offset is not required since the objects are inside the frame.
U can simply use 
((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", Element);

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest two solution , either switch to default frame after clicking on th search button or move your cursor to a different element in the page.
See this below two methods that might help you out.

```
/**
 * @author mbn217
 * @Date -----
 * @Purpose This method will helps us to switch to a default content
 * @param N/A
 * @return N/A
 */
public static void switchToDefaultContent() {
    log.info("Switching o default content");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

}
```

Second Method will hover you mouse to an element you choose in the web page

```
/**
 * @author mbn217
 * @Date -----
 * @Purpose This method will hover to an element
 * @param HovertoWebElement --> element of the webpage
 * @return N/A
 */ 
public static void hoverToWebelement(WebElement HovertoWebElement) throws InterruptedException {
    log.info("Hovering over an element");
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(HovertoWebElement).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Good Luck!